# Matching the row numbers from a which() output to the rows of another column containing ENSEMBL ID's

Tags: r

So I have some gene expression count data with the columns containing all my samples and each row containing ~60000 genes shown by a list of ENSEMBL ID's. I've transformed the data to TPM and changed all non-zero values to a "1" using the following code:

```
df[df != 0] <- 1

ENSEMBL           Sample A  Sample B  Sample C  Sample D
ENSG00000210082   1         1         0         1
ENSG00000166710   1         1         0         1
ENSG00000163220   1         0         1         0
...
```

Then I applied `which(df$sampleA == 1)` and gives me an output of which rows in sample A contain a "1".

```
1 2 ... 15652 16516 16607
```

So my question is, how do I match these row numbers to the rows of the column containing ENSEMBL ID's? (ie. I want to know which genes have non-zero TPM values?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df[which(df$sampleA == 1), ]$ENSEMBL
```

Comment: R just gives me  "Error in `[.data.frame`(df, which(df$sampleA == 1) : 
  undefined columns selected", maybe there's something going wrong after I use 'df[df != 0] <- 1'?

Comment: I forgot a comma, it should be working now.

Comment: So that does work now but it just gives me an output of a bunch of 1's. I think what's happening is when I apply `df[df != 0] <- 1` it sets all my ENSEMBL ID's to 1 as well...

Comment: yeah, could you try `df[-1][df[-1] != 0] <- 1` instead?